# Sn1 Stereochemistry and Energy

Tags: organic-chemistry

1. [image]

Sn2 has simultaneous bond breaking and forming because it's concerted.

Sn1....does it occur with a loss of stereochemistry at the reactive center? An online textbook says so.

Sn1 has both retention and inversion of config. So don't know which one fits Sn1. Only one statement is true for SN1.

2. Which of the energy diagrams shown below represents an exothermic SN1 reaction?

[image]

It would be graph A because Sn1 is stepwise two steps. And it's exo because of -E?

Comment: Homework questions must demonstrate some effort to understand the underlying concepts. For help asking a good homework question, see: How do I ask homework questions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an AMIRITE question, too localized to help future visitors. Please include an answer not in your question, but in the form of an answer with full details of your reasoning.

Comment: @Klaus Warzecha Not off-topic because I gave my reasoning. Only statement I couldn't reason is if SN1 "occurs with a loss of stereochemistry at the reactive center" since it's not in my notes.